# Cached template generated classes/functions

Tags: c++, templates

One of the reasons for the long compilation of programs written in c++ is templates. As far as I know, with each recompilation of code(even hot recompilation), the compiler is forced to generate types from templates again.

So I wondered if it would be better to cache the generated types. In this case, we would only have to regenerate the types if we use a new template type, or if we change the template code.

I tried to find something about this topics in google, but seems, like I am the first one to ask this question. So after failure with direct question
I decided to find some unobvious way where my idea could already be realized. I suspected that precompiled headers somehow implemented this, but tests show that this is not the case. Compilation time of 3 template types does not change with recompilation(but still it is faster than without PCH, obviously).

Maybe I'm missing something. So did any compiler implement the caching of the generated types. If not, why?

Comment: it is unclear what you mean. Also compilers have been getting smarter in the last decades and many issues with compilation of templates have been fixed.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number so the easiest implementation of my idea is creating separate *.o file for each generated class(aka ```vector_int.o``` or smt like this). And when next time I will try to recompile my code, instead of generating and compiling new ```vector<int>``` again, it just get already compiled code from ```vector_int.o```

Comment: @Deumaudit There is explicit instantiation which basically does that.

Comment: @user17732522 what do you mean?

Comment: Long compilation is also due to huge number of files to open/parse. C++20 Module might allow to reduce that.

Comment: @Deumaudit You can explicitly instantiate a class template in one translation unit and use it without the need for implicit instantiation in other translation units, which is basically what you described in your previous comment. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation. It is a common technique to reduce compilation time if you know the relevant types for the template a priori.

Comment: @user17732522 not exactly. As good as I understand, explicit templates still regenerate class itself(but only once). In my case I want avoid regenerating at all. So I compile my program for the first time(```vector<int>``` is generating and compiling, than saving to file ```vector_int.o```). Second time when I compile my code, compiler recognize my ```vector_int.o``` file and instead of generating new ```vector<int>``` it takes the same type from file

Comment: @Deumaudit With explicit instantiation the definitions of the template members can be in a source file. The source file with the explicit instantiations then only needs to be recompiled when they are modified. Of course this is not done automatically. There would be a lot of problems with doing this automatically. The code must be written to make use of this feature.